# How to find the KML layer used in this map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm pretty new to the google maps API, but from what I understand about KML layers, this map probably uses one. However, I'm not sure how to find it. I looked at the javascript used in this web page, but I can't seem to find the KML. Please help.

[Here's the link](http://aidsvu.org/map)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One of the referenced .js files is http://maplarge.com/AidsMapV5.js. On line 2730 of that file is:

```
getTileUrl: function (level, row, col) {
    return "http://api.maplarge.com/Tile/Tile?z=" + level + "&x=" + col + "&y=" + row +
    "&layer=" + layerString + "&filter=" + filterString + "&shader=" + shaderString;
}
```

They're using an API called [Map Large](http://maplarge.com/API) and that's where the layers come from.